# Default text-to-speech (TTS) engine in LineageOS 16.0?

Tags: lineageos, 9.0-pie, accessibility, text-to-speech

I have recently updated my OnePlus One to LineageOS 16.0 and noticed that there does not seem to be *any* TTS provider included anymore. In previous versions (LineageOS 15), there used to be Pico TTS as a default.

What happened here? Is there any way to get Pico TTS back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pico TTS is unmaintained and dead. At least publicly. Presumably, the fixed version of it is what is now called "Googls TTS", which is no longer open source.

My suggestion, if you're looking for an open source TTS, is to use Flite TTS, which is available via F-Droid repository or from github.

https://f-droid.org/en/packages/edu.cmu.cs.speech.tts.flite/

Comment: Link is dead (404), so unfortunately this answer no longer doesn't hold true any longer. It seems to have been unpublished with this repo having the last commits >6 years ago, with the latest APK now most likely being incompatible with recent Android versions: https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android